# Alignment in HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment

i want to display text like:

```
Name    Age
Susan   9
Joe     20
```

I've tried to use {div align="right"}, but the output looks like:

```
Name                             Age
Susan                            9
Joe                               20
```

and so on. How can i list the items on each row so that they line up properly with the header?

Comment: use table td to make it

Comment: @JFOXX, it would be better to include your code here for people to help

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to layout the information above neatly, maybe a table would be better.

Try using the following example instead:

```
<div> 
  <table border = "1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Age:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Susan</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you include an example of your code it may help to understand further.